# Is MemTest86+ Testing All My Memory?

Tags: boot, memory, memtest86+

I have a Lenovo D20 workstation that's crashing on boot. 64GB of memory are installed, but /proc/meminfo reports only 2.94GB available, so I'm running memtest86+ to check for memory errors. The system has eight 8GB DIMMs, and memtest confirms this; "Show DMI Memory Info" reports 12 memory sockets total, 8 populated with 8GB each.

However, the main memtest page only lists four DIMMs under "Memory SPD Information". Is memtest testing all eight DIMMs and only showing four, or are only four being tested?

Machine:
2x Intel Xeon X5570
8x Samsung 8GB DDR3 DIMM M393B1K70CH0-YH9
DIMMs installed to slots 1,2,3,4 for each processor socket (slots 00,01,10,20,30,31,40,50 in meminfo).

Comment: Does the BIOS indicate all the memory installed in the slots?

Comment: It sounds like a case of 2 physical processors not being supported. this tool has been upgraded over time to include the full 64bit of memory (cool) but the bootdisk software (mini os) that it boots with might not yet support 2 physical processors.

Comment: The BIOS does not list information for the RAM anywhere I can find.

Not supporting two processors is very possible. Is there a work-around for specifying the processor to use? I can't find anything in the memtest86+ config settings. I can physically swap the eight DIMMs so that I can test the other four, but that's a bit of a kludge.

Comment: Back to the original issue of the memory not being addressed and looking like it is stuck under the 4gig adressing limit thing. Most motherboards even back in time some, have an "extended memory" switch in the bios/uefi, it is not always called that but it changes the MB to addressing the memory 64bit style.   Then the crashing, in many situations large quantities of memory are not tested, even if it IS on the compatability list. The memory could require the timings to be loosened a bit to work fully when all of it is there and running at high rates.  Sorry i do not even know what OS you use?